# Treeview with Checkboxes simple html with Css

Tags: html, css, treeview

I am looking for a treeview format for my ipfire backup system.
where the users need to select the folders for update. like in the image-->

Exemple

[image]

the server script is CGI Perl but i can implement simple HTML and CSS or very simple JS.
I need the parent folders if checked to check automaticly the content

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your HTML but if it fits this

```
<div class="tree">
  <input type="checkbox" /> 1.
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /> 1.1.
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> 1.1.1.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if you use the jQuery library you could do it like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tree input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    checkParent($(this));
  });

  function checkParent(element) {
    if (element.prop('checked')) {
      var parent = element.parent().parent().find('> input[type="checkbox"]');

      if (parent.length) {
        parent.prop('checked', true);
        checkParent(parent);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tree input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    checkParent($(this));
  });

  function checkParent(element) {
    if (element.prop('checked')) {
      var parent = element.parent().parent().find('> input[type="checkbox"]');

      if (parent.length) {
        parent.prop('checked', true);
        checkParent(parent);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree">
  <input type="checkbox" /> 1.
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /> 1.1.
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> 1.1.1.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```